# Pushing Functions to array logs 'undefined' in the array

Tags: javascript

I'm just wondering why the console reads `[undefined, undefined, undefined]` when I log the contents of the array.

Here's the code, I guess I was expecting the console to log the contents of the array as `[runIt(1), runIt(2), runIt(3)]`

```
var myArr = [];

myArr.push( runIt(1) );
myArr.push( runIt(2) );
myArr.push( runIt(3) );
console.log(myArr);

function runIt (num) {
    console.log(num);  
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not pushing the functions, you're pushing the results of **calling** the functions.

If you want to push functions that call "runIt", you'll have to make them:

```
myArr.push( function() { runIt(1); } );
```

You could make a "runItRunner" function:

```
function runItRunner( arg ) {
  return function() {
    runIt( arg );
  };
}
```

Then:

```
myArr.push( runItRunner(1) );
myArr.push( runItRunner(2) );
// etc
```